# R string vector error - the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r, string, conditional-statements

I need help with the following R code - my code is:

```
best <- function(state, outcome) { 
        ## Read outcome data
        outcome <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character") enter code here

        ## Check that state and outcome are valid using STOP function and
        ## message "invalid state" or "invalid outcome"

        valid_outcomes <- c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")

        if(!state %in% state.abb){
                stop("Invalid state")
        }  
        else if (!outcome %in% valid_outcomes)
        {
                stop("Invalid outcome") 
        }

        return(x)
        ## Return hospital name in that state with lowest 30-day death ## rate
}
```

It returns:

```
Error in best("NY", "health") : Invalid outcome
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!outcome %in% valid_outcomes) { :
   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

If I use else if (any(!outcome %in% valid_outcomes)) it seems to help, but the logical condition isn't being resolved properly.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 if(!any(state == data$State)) {
    stop('invalid state')
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is evaluating a vector of output whereas it is designed to take only one logical value. Try this code to see the issue:

```
> outcome <- c('one', 'two', 'pneumonia')
> valid_outcomes <- c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")
> outcome %in% valid_outcomes
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

You see that it returns a vector of true/false values. To put them all into one condition, you can use:

```
if (!all(outcome %in% valid_outcomes)) { stop('blah') }
```

Same issue for the states that you need to fix.